# Log doesn't display Location data

Tags: java, android, permissions, gps, location

I am doing an Android course, where we learn how to fetch location data. Following the instructor, I think I made the app exactly like he said, altough, I dont get any location data in my Android Monitor.

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3, and run the app on a huaweii p10 lite.

The code looks like this, quite basic actually:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LocationManager locationManager;

LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.i("Location", location.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }

    };

    // If device is running SDK < 23

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    } else {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // ask for permission

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);


        } else {

            // we have permission!

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        }

    }

}
```

}

the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.robpercival.locationdemo">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hey Alexander! Thank you for your fast answer! If I leave the toString() out it gives me an error right away:

Error:(52, 39) error: incompatible types: Location cannot be converted to String

I've used the placeholder as well, but my log still doesn't display the location data :/ :(

Comment: It feels like that the compiler doesn't even pass permission phase, or gets it wrong, and so onLocationChanged is never been called. Tried Toast instead of Logging, and textView as well, I just don't get the Location data :/

Comment: I've got a longer cable, just to move the phone around, meaning that I really change location, and I got these:
HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config